# not receiving data from http post

Tags: php, python, http-post

I am using python code to send a http post request and on the other side(server) am using php script to get the data and send the acknowledgement to the client.
When I try to send the data to the server it is not receiving it. I am getting 'nothing' as my response which am trying to print when it could not read the data.

Here is my python code,

```
# importing the requests library
import requests

# defining the api-endpoint 
API_ENDPOINT = "http://192.168.X.XX/response.php"

# your source code here
Driver-id = 'TN597098'
Driver-name = 'XXXX'
# data to be sent to api
data = {'driverid':Driver-id,'drivername':Driver-name}

# sending post request and saving response as response object
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)

# extracting response text 
response = r.text
print("The response is:%s"%response)
```

Here is my php script,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['driverid'])) {
    echo $_GET['driverid'];
    } else {
    echo "nothing";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing POST call from python script and expecting GET in php script thats why it is not working.
You can change your php code to

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['driverid'])) {
     echo $_POST['driverid'];
    } else {
    echo "nothing";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sendind the request using http post method  then in PHP you must use $_POST

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['driverid'])) {
    echo $_POST['driverid'];
 } else {
         echo "nothing";
 }
```

you must use the same method both side